Unable to redirect back to Kotlin Mobile app after login using Google Account
I have created a Kotlin Mobile app to Use Gmail API. But after login with Google account it will not automatically redirect back to the app. Can you please help me with this?
`This is my source code.
 private val SCOPES = setOf(
        GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS,  // メールのラベルを取得する権限
        GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY,   // メールを読み取る権限
        GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY,  // メールのラベルの修正や送信なども行える権限
    )

    val APP_STORAGE_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE: Int = 501 // Any value


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)



        Log.d("DEBUG","T")
        var authBtn = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button) as Button
        authBtn.setOnClickListener(){
            runGmailAUth()

        }
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets

        }
}
    
    fun getCredentials(

        httpTransport: NetHttpTransport,
        jsonFactory: GsonFactory,
        credentialsFilePath: String = "credentials.json",
        tokenDir: String = "tokens"
    ): Credential? {
        // OAuth認証情報の読み込み
        val inputStream = getAssets().open(credentialsFilePath)
        // json形式の認証情報を読み込む
        val clientSecrets: GoogleClientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets
            .load(jsonFactory, InputStreamReader(inputStream))

        val appWorkingDirectory = getApplicationInfo().dataDir
        val dataDirectory = File(appWorkingDirectory, tokenDir)

        // 認証フローの設定をする。
        val flow: GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow = GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
            .Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(FileDataStoreFactory(dataDirectory)) // トークン保存先ディレクトリの指定
            .setAccessType("offline")  // web applicationの場合はonline, それ以外はoffline
            .build()

I suspect the error might be with this line of code.The browser will not open the app after complete login.
        val receiver = LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build()

        val ab: AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp =
            object : AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver) {
                @Throws(IOException::class)
                override fun onAuthorization(authorizationUrl: AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl) {
                    val url = authorizationUrl.build()
                    val browserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
                    startActivity(browserIntent)
                }
            }

        return ab.authorize("user").setAccessToken("user")
   }

    fun runGmailAUth() {
        val jsonFactory: GsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
        Log.d("TAG", "runGmailAuth() Function")
        // Googleが提供するHTTPクライアントを生成(これは、通常のNetHttpTransportにGoogle API用のルート証明書が埋め込まれていたりするようです。)
        val httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()

        val credential = getCredentials(httpTransport, jsonFactory, "credentials.json")
        // Gmail serviceを作成。Gmailの各種操作には以降このserviceを使用します。
        val service: Gmail = Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("kotlin-gmail-reader")
            .build()
        readMailAndRemoveUnread(service)  // 下で実装します
    }

    fun readMailAndRemoveUnread(service: Gmail) {
        // code to send mail.
    }

    data class MailMessage(val date: String, val from: String, val subject: String, val body: String)

